# Position image to right, trailing off screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to position my image trailing off the screen and for it to appear like that on any resolution or device. Does it need to be a background image?

```
<section class="meet">
    <div class="meet01">
        <img src="img/keyboard.png" class="keyboard">
        <img src="img/blue_frame.png">
        <h1><strong>Hello.</strong></h1>
       <img src="img/mouse.png" class="mouse">
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Style>
.oneh
{
float:right !important;
width:100%;
position:relative;
height:auto;
margin-right:-40% !important;
}
.meet01
{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<section class="meet">
    <div class="meet01">
        <img src="img/keyboard.png" class="oneh keyboard">
        <img src="img/blue_frame.png">
        <h1><strong>Hello.</strong></h1>
        <img src="img/mouse.png" class="mouse">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't know about your other classes as you haven't provided the code of the maybe their css behaves differently. so what i was able to think is of this solutions try it. It you think thats the answer then accept the answer and vote up. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to make the image still crop off the screen without it extending the horizontal scroll?

Comment: well you have the same thing by using css  propert overflow:hidden on the container div of the image, this will not show anything goes outside the boundary of div

Comment: wait let me add that in answer

Comment: accept the answer if your doubt is clear and upvote if you find it usefull : )